# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '3' of undefined

Tags: javascript

Tengo un problema en javascript y no veo como solucionarlo. He mirado otra gente con un mensaje de error similar, y lo que parece es como si no tuviera una propiedad un objeto, pero en mi caso si que la tiene (o al menos eso creo)

La función que da el error es la siguiente:

```
function Winner(id,r,c)
{
  if (r>=0 && r<=g_num_rows-4 &&
        g_table_board.DATA[r  ][c]==id &&
        g_table_board.DATA[r+1][c]==id &&
        g_table_board.DATA[r+2][c]==id &&
        g_table_board.DATA[r+3][c]==id)
      return true;

  return false
}
```

id es 1, r y c son 3, g_num_rows es 7

g_table_board se define como sigue:

```
function TableBoard(r,c)
{
    this.NR = r;
    this.NC = c;

    this.DATA = new Array(this.NR);
    for (var i=0; i<this.NR; i++)
    {
        this.DATA[i] = new Array(this.NC);
        for (var j=0; j<this.NC; j++)
          this.DATA[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
```

y se ha inicializado como:

```
g_table_board = new TableBoard(7,7);
```

la llamada a Winner que da el error es

```
Winner(1,3,3)
```

El error lo da al evaluar la cuarta condición:

```
g_table_board.DATA[r+1][c]==id
```

Curiosamente, usando las herramientas del chrome, cuando pongo el siguiente watch:

```
g_table_board.DATA[r]
```

me da el valor correcto, pero al poner :

```
g_table_board.DATA[r+1]
```

me dice undefined

Y si pongo:

```
g_table_board.DATA[r-1]
```

me da el valor correcto

En otras partes del código tengo condiciones similares y no me da ningún problema, por ejemplo está condición funciona bien:

```
  if (r>=3 && r<=g_num_rows-1 &&
      g_table_board.DATA[r-3][c]==id &&
      g_table_board.DATA[r-2][c]==id &&
      g_table_board.DATA[r-1][c]==id &&
      g_table_board.DATA[r  ][c]==id)
    return true;
```

¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He encontrado el error, r es un string, y entonces r+1 está concatenando "3" y "1" en vez de sumarlos.

Comment: Podrías marcar tu respuesta como correcta si quieres, para cerrar la pregunta! Saludos!